# Xcode 7 storyboard issue for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I am new to Xcode and with the latest version of Xcode 7 installed.  When I tried working with the storyboard, I have noticed that I cannot align the position of my objects correctly for my iPad.  I know iPad shares the same layout for Portrait and Landscape but I can only get either one aligned correctly.  May I know whether I can use different constraint for portrait and landscape like with iPhone for the iPad ?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

With your storyboard opened in Xcode look at the bottom in the center, you will see "w**Any** h**Any**".

[image: Xcode storyboard set size]

Clicking on this label will enable you to view your storyboard for any device, dragging your cursor to the bottom right of the popup menu will enable you to view your storyboard as an iPad.

[image]

Once you set this to "w**Regular** h**Regular**" the constraints will act as you expect.

Comment: Thanks.  But I have tried but no matter how I tune the left constraint, it can either align Portrait OR Landscape but not both.  In fact, I was hoping to group multiple labels together and horizontally centre align them together but I don't know how to performing the grouping and therefore I constraint the left most object to adjust the constraint value to make this work for iPhone but not iPad.  Can you advise ?

Thanks

Comment: @PeterP sounds like your trying to do a lot in one step. Firstly the different w and h settings are for different devices. i.e. wRegular hRegular will let you align and constrain objects for iPad. Then you need to change to wCompact rHeight for iPhone portrait & set your alignments and constraints. Then switch to wCompact hCompact for iPhone Landscape and set new alignments and constraints.

Comment: @PeterP as for grouping objects together, add a UIView and nest your objects in there, it allows you to nest constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  The reason I need to have different constraints for Portrait and Landscape on an iPad is I cannot use a single left constrain to align them correctly on both views (Port and Land).  For iPhone it's much easier since I can assign them differently.

As mentioned, I want to do the centre align IF I can group them together so may be easier for me to align them together.